# Maintain concealed text in quickfix buffer

Tags: quickfix

Would like to maintain the concealed text in the locationlist (aka quickfix) from the targeted file, which has the extension .rex .

For example, the target file is  has:
+-
concealed to
±

The quicklist still shows 
+-

This is an example which contain a small portion of concealed text. I also have a concealed text which has more characters, and would be nice to shorten to have more space for other information.

Answer (score 1):

Concealing is just changing the visual appearance of the content of your window. As such, it always happens local to the window in which it was defined.

Since the quickfix buffer is displayed in another window, concealing from the original window won't happen there and you need to define it there additionally.

So to make this work, you might just enter the following command in your quickfix (or locationlist) window:

```
:call matchadd('Conceal', '+-', 10, -1, {'conceal': '±'})
```

If you want to have this happen, you might need to run a command like this on a WinEnter (or BufWinEnter) autocommand. It might also be possible to run it on QuickFixCmdPre or Post autocommand, not exactly sure and it might depend on how the quickfix list is created.